# ERROR: operator does not exist: character = integer

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, postgresql-9.1

Here is my DaoImpl class.I have the other table tblprofiles in which field email is primary key.how can get tbldealusers data in whcih email as foreign key of type character. when i run this program,I am getting error like

ERROR: operator does not exist: character = integer

tbldealusers having OneToMany relation with tblProfiles

```
 public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao 
    {

        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        DealUser dealuser=new DealUser();
        private Session session=null;
        Profiles profiles=new Profiles();

        @Autowired
        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) 
        {
            this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")      
         public List<DealUser> getAllDealUsers() 
         {
            session =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
             List<DealUser> dealUsers =  (List<DealUser>) session.
                    createSQLQuery("select * from tbldealusers u ")
                    .addEntity("u", DealUser.class)
                     .list();

            return dealUsers;
         }
```

my execption stack trace

```
Hibernate: select * from tbldealusers u
Hibernate: select profiles0_.email as email1_, profiles0_.email as email9_0_, profiles0_.firstnname as firstnname9_0_, profiles0_.lastname as lastname9_0_, profiles0_.mobile as mobile9_0_, profiles0_.notifyflash as notifyfl5_9_0_, profiles0_.is_active as is6_9_0_, profiles0_.tac_preferenceluid as tac7_9_0_, profiles0_.createddate as createdd8_9_0_, profiles0_.modifieddate as modified9_9_0_, profiles0_.createduserid as created10_9_0_, profiles0_.modifieduserid as modifie11_9_0_ from tblprofiles profiles0_ where profiles0_.email=?
2014-03-18 16:19:55 WARN  JDBCExceptionReporter:77 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42883
2014-03-18 16:19:55 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - ERROR: operator does not exist: character = integer
Mar 18, 2014 4:19:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlet-context] in context with path [/SaveDollar] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not initialize a collection: [com.saveDollar.model.DealUser.profiles#1]] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character = integer
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1608)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1343)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:194)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:470)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:369)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1778)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:1985)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:565)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1716)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:454)
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:755)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:150)
    at com.saveDollar.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl.getAllDealUsers(UserDaoImpl.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy24.getAllDealUsers(Unknown Source)
    at com.saveDollar.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.getAllDealUsers(UserServiceImpl.java:19)
    at com.saveDollar.controller.UserRestService.loadUsers(UserRestService.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code

```
package com.saveDollar.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
@Entity(name="tbldealusers")
public class DealUser implements Serializable 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      private int  userid;
      private String email;
      private String password;
      private int typeofuserluid;
      private boolean is_deleted;
      private Set<Profiles> profiles = new HashSet<Profiles>(0);      

      public DealUser()
      {

      }

      public DealUser(String email,String password,int typeofuserluid,boolean is_deleted,Set<Profiles> profiles)
         {

             this.email=email;
             this.password=password;
             this.typeofuserluid=typeofuserluid;
             this.is_deleted=is_deleted;
             this.profiles=profiles;

        }  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="userid") 
    public int getUserid() 
    {
        return userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(int userid) 
    {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    @Column(name="email") 
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    @Column(name="password") 
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    @Column(name="typeofuserluid") 
    public int getTypeofuserluid() {
        return typeofuserluid;
    }
    public void setTypeofuserluid(int typeofuserluid) {
        this.typeofuserluid = typeofuserluid;
    }
    @Column(name="is_deleted") 
    public boolean isIs_deleted() {
        return is_deleted;
    }
    public void setIs_deleted(boolean is_deleted) 
    {
        this.is_deleted = is_deleted;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "email",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Profiles> getProfiles() 
    {
        return profiles;
    }

    public void setProfiles(Set<Profiles> profiles) 
    {
        this.profiles = profiles;
    }
}
```

please any suggestions.Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions

Comment: Can you paste complete exception stack trace ..It will be easy to find issue for us

Comment: @Youngistan thanks for your response.here i paste my execption stack trace

Comment: Can you paste com.saveDollar.model.DealUser class.

Comment: can you tell me how to cast email of tblProfiles to character in bean class?

Comment: It may be a language gap, but you can't simply cast a table of Profile objects to a character, or String for that matter.  Casting doesn't work that way.  If you want to turn it into a String, you could overwrite the toString() method or use some serialization method.

Comment: @Kick I don't see how stack trace is relevant here

Comment: Why do you use SQL rather than JPQL. And why in hell is the session a field rather than a local variable. Your DAO isn't thread-safe.